# Center HTML Object Horizontally and Vertically

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know these questions get asked tons of times, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get my object centered vertically.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/3aVjV/1/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="demo-3 demo-dark js boxshadow pointerevents placeholder">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <service class="main">
                    <ul class="bokeh">
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </service>
            </div>
        </body>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.main {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
/* DEMO 3 */
 .demo-3 body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
.demo-3 body:after {
    content:"";
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.demo-3 .bokeh {
    font-size: 100px;
    width: .5em;
    height: .5em;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: .01em solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.3);
    list-style: none;
}
.demo-3 .bokeh li {
    position: absolute;
    width: .1em;
    height: .1em;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.demo-3 .bokeh li:nth-child(1) {
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -.05em;
    background: #00C176;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 250%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 250%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 250%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 250%;
    transform-origin: 50% 250%;
    -webkit-animation: rota 1.13s linear infinite, opa 3.67s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: rota 1.13s linear infinite, opa 3.67s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: rota 1.13s linear infinite, opa 3.67s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: rota 1.13s linear infinite, opa 3.67s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: rota 1.13s linear infinite, opa 3.67s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.demo-3 .bokeh li:nth-child(2) {
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin: -.05em 0 0 0;
    background: #FF003C;
    -webkit-transform-origin: -150% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: -150% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: -150% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: -150% 50%;
    transform-origin: -150% 50%;
    -webkit-animation: rota 1.86s linear infinite, opa 4.29s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: rota 1.86s linear infinite, opa 4.29s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: rota 1.86s linear infinite, opa 4.29s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: rota 1.86s linear infinite, opa 4.29s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: rota 1.86s linear infinite, opa 4.29s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.demo-3 .bokeh li:nth-child(3) {
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -.05em;
    background: #FABE28;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% -150%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% -150%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% -150%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% -150%;
    transform-origin: 50% -150%;
    -webkit-animation: rota 1.45s linear infinite, opa 5.12s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: rota 1.45s linear infinite, opa 5.12s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: rota 1.45s linear infinite, opa 5.12s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: rota 1.45s linear infinite, opa 5.12s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: rota 1.45s linear infinite, opa 5.12s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
.demo-3 .bokeh li:nth-child(4) {
    top: 50%;
    left 0;
    margin: -.05em 0 0 0;
    background: #88C100;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 250% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 250% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 250% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 250% 50%;
    transform-origin: 250% 50%;
    -webkit-animation: rota 1.72s linear infinite, opa 5.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -moz-animation: rota 1.72s linear infinite, opa 5.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -ms-animation: rota 1.72s linear infinite, opa 5.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    -o-animation: rota 1.72s linear infinite, opa 5.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
    animation: rota 1.72s linear infinite, opa 5.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rota {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes rota {
    to {
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes rota {
    to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes rota {
    to {
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@keyframes rota {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes opa {
    12.0% {
        opacity: 0.80;
    }
    19.5% {
        opacity: 0.88;
    }
    37.2% {
        opacity: 0.64;
    }
    40.5% {
        opacity: 0.52;
    }
    52.7% {
        opacity: 0.69;
    }
    60.2% {
        opacity: 0.60;
    }
    66.6% {
        opacity: 0.52;
    }
    70.0% {
        opacity: 0.63;
    }
    79.9% {
        opacity: 0.60;
    }
    84.2% {
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
    91.0% {
        opacity: 0.87;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes opa {
    12.0% {
        opacity: 0.80;
    }
    19.5% {
        opacity: 0.88;
    }
    37.2% {
        opacity: 0.64;
    }
    40.5% {
        opacity: 0.52;
    }
    52.7% {
        opacity: 0.69;
    }
    60.2% {
        opacity: 0.60;
    }
    66.6% {
        opacity: 0.52;
    }
    70.0% {
        opacity: 0.63;
    }
    79.9% {
        opacity: 0.60;
    }
    84.2% {
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
    91.0% {
        opacity: 0.87;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes opa {
    12.0% {
        opacity: 0.80;
    }
    19.5% {
        opacity: 0.88;
    }
    37.2% {
        opacity: 0.64;
    }
    40.5% {
        opacity: 0.52;
    }
    52.7% {
        opacity: 0.69;
    }
    60.2% {
        opacity: 0.60;
    }
    66.6% {
        opacity: 0.52;
    }
    70.0% {
        opacity: 0.63;
    }
    79.9% {
        opacity: 0.60;
    }
    84.2% {
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
    91.0% {
        opacity: 0.87;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes opa {
    12.0% {
        opacity: 0.80;
    }
    19.5% {
        opacity: 0.88;
    }
    37.2% {
        opacity: 0.64;
    }
    40.5% {
        opacity: 0.52;
    }
    52.7% {
        opacity: 0.69;
    }
    60.2% {
        opacity: 0.60;
    }
    66.6% {
        opacity: 0.52;
    }
    70.0% {
        opacity: 0.63;
    }
    79.9% {
        opacity: 0.60;
    }
    84.2% {
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
    91.0% {
        opacity: 0.87;
    }
}
@keyframes opa {
    12.0% {
        opacity: 0.80;
    }
    19.5% {
        opacity: 0.88;
    }
    37.2% {
        opacity: 0.64;
    }
    40.5% {
        opacity: 0.52;
    }
    52.7% {
        opacity: 0.69;
    }
    60.2% {
        opacity: 0.60;
    }
    66.6% {
        opacity: 0.52;
    }
    70.0% {
        opacity: 0.63;
    }
    79.9% {
        opacity: 0.60;
    }
    84.2% {
        opacity: 0.75;
    }
    91.0% {
        opacity: 0.87;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your code here.

Comment: You have to use javascript or pre-determined units. *There is no other way* with CSS.

Comment: Heya. Second @putvande, please post a [minimal example](http://sscce.org) in the question as well so it's independent from any linked site. In addition it'd help if you explain how your problem is different from "questions asked tons of times", and what you've tried so far to fix the issue.

Comment: vertical-align: center ?

Comment: @Vadorequest that has nothing to do with this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you invent the <s>`<service>`</s> tag? That's invalid markup, and as far as the centering goes, use `position: absolute;` instead.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3aVjV/4/)

```
.main {
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* You can get rid of this, just for test purpose */
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 50%; /* 50% from top */
    left: 50%; /* 50% from left */
    margin-top: -25px; /* 1/2 of height which will set the top offset */
    margin-left: -25px; /* 1/2 if width which will set the left offset */
}
```

Comment: You rock, thanks!  No I didn't, I just found the code online and that's what they had.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Not sure if you should put a strikethrough over the tag you reference. It may be made up but I think it's clear that it's fictitious by the context of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Real simple..

1. get window height
2. get object height
3. divide window height by 2, divide object height by 2.
4. subtract `object/2` from `window/2`. This is your top margin for the object.

Voila.

Comment: document.height, document.width in pure JS.

Comment: @Vadorequest better to use `window` as it's more accurate and fail-proof. no need for width, `margin:auto` will handle it provided it stays relative. if absolute, copy, replace height with width, repeat for margin left. `text-align:center` if the div is 100% width.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, my bad, I'm doing too much mongoDb I guess! And usually use jQuery, pure JS isn't for me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar approach to Mr. Alien, but I modified your `.main` and your `.demo-3 .bokeh` classes (below):

```
.main {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

.demo-3 .bokeh {
    font-size: 100px;
    width: .5em;
    height: .5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left: -25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: .01em solid rgba(150,150,150,0.3);
    list-style: none;
}
```

**[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3aVjV/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

This solution works even if one day you decide to change the loader size.

Basically, changed the parent to have a position absolute and I did some magic for the child
But you can center anything using this technique. Check link for the result

```
.main {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
position: absolute;
}

.demo-3 .bokeh {

font-size: 100px;
position: absolute;

width: .5em;
height: .5em;

border-radius: 50%;
border: .01em solid rgba(150,150,150,0.3);
list-style: none;

margin: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

**Fiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/ositoozy/A6QRU/